# HTTPS version of my site isn't functioning like how it supposed to

Tags: html, https

Recently I got a SSL Cert. for my site, but when I use the **https** version of my site, some functions don't work.

Example:
http://www.lockheedlee.com/social.html
(when you click on the thumbnails, and image will fade in)

https://www.lockheedlee.com/social.html
(when you click on the thumbnails, it will direct you to the image)

Can someone let me know what the issue is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your jquery library is not downloaded from the CDN in the https website.
This is because you are trying to request "http" site from a "https" origin.

Change all your resource files links from http to https and everything should be fine.

Comment: thanks Lakshman, not sure of how to do this. Is this something that I must request from Godaddy or I must do manually my self? I thought once I purchase the SSL cert. from them, that all would be is set and done?

Comment: Godaddy would not be doing this for you. You need to ask your webmaster to this or if you access to the server you can do this yourself.